# saved order at API in woocommerce_thankyou page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Invoice information on the woocoommerce_thankyou page is curled by a web service. If the user does not see this page for any reason, how can the storage operation be performed? Can invoice storage action be changed in any other way?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'club_add_factor', 10, 1 );
function club_add_factor( $order_id ) {
if ( ! $order_id ) {
    return;
}
/* Get order info */
$order         = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$userID        = $order->get_customer_id();
$api           = new Club( $userID );
// something ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, "woocommerce_thankyou" handles the following hooks collectively. But when you are not landing on thankyou page, you can use on-hold or processing instead.

```
//add_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'club_add_factor');
//add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'club_add_factor');
//add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'club_add_factor');
//add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'club_add_factor');

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'club_add_factor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bro !
I solved it with 'woocommerce_order_status_processing' action.
I used it :

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'club_add_factor');
```